# Best method for fixing chips in laminate flooring

Tags: laminate-floor

I'm looking for recommendations or techniques to repair some chips on our "homeowner" installed laminate. We have several spots where the tapping block did some damage - we were limited on the boxes of product so we just have to live with our woopses. Any help or recommendations are welcome and appreciated.

[image: chip 1]

[image: chip 2]

Comment: If it chips and discolors that easily, I wouldn't expect it to last long under wear and tear.

Comment: @dandavis Most of them are in very low traffic areas - in places where we are putting furniture or behind doors.

Comment: Move the damaged ones to edges or where they are or will be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

The boards near the wall should be replaced before you install trim, if possible. No repair will completely hide the damage.

Most manufacturers provide a means of replacing interior boards. Consider that for a professional result.

Otherwise, the boards in the field could be touched up with some enamel paint. You'll have to experiment with a base color and accent/grain colors. A matte varnish (urethane) might help match sheen, which is a big part of the challenge.

Comment: So the bottom image will for sure be outside the baseboard - issue with that piece is that it's underneath a door jamb. None of the scuffs or damaged boards are in good places to be replaced. So I will look into that enamel paint option, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I would check with the MFG. Back when I was still doing flooring, I used a lot of pergo, and they had a filler that matched the product coloring quite well.  even without the grain It made it hard to find the oh woopsi, I use an out house word.
I have found similar repair kits for Formica counter tops to hide seams when the color match is exact the lack of grain is not so bad.